# C# Better way to shorten repeated code

Tags: c#, winforms

the following code allows me to have a hover over image on a button but requires a load of repeated code. I was wondering if there is a way to shorten down and allow the same piece of code to be used but with a different button name.

I know the `private void *NAME*`can be the same, used by different buttons and allows me to shorten the following but then leaves me with the hover over being on all the buttons at once rather than individually.

```
private void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    private void btnfb_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnfb.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    void btnfb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnfb.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.hover_img));
    }

    private void btndiscord_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btndiscord.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    void btndiscord_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.btndiscord.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.hover_img));
    }

    private void btn_pp_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btn_pp.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    void btn_pp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.btn_pp.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.hover_img));
    }

    private void btnhelp_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnhelp.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    void btnhelp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnhelp.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.hover_img));
    }

    private void btnsave_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnsave.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }

    void btnsave_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnsave.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.hover_img));
    }

    private void btnmini_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnmini.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
    }
```

Comment: Use C# 'Delegate'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wire up all your event to the same handler ...

```
private void MyButtonLeaveHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Button button = sender as Button;
 if (button != null)
 { 
     button.BackgroundImage = ((Image)(Properties.Resources.leave_img));
 }
}
```

Saying

```
this.button1.Leave += MyButtonLeaveHandler;
this.btnfb.Leave += MyButtonLeaveHandler;
```

Similarly you can create abother common handler for `MouseLeave` event

Comment: But wouldn't that only set button1's background to have the leave_img only? since it also would need to be be on btn_pp, etc at different times.

Comment: Using your example, where is states 'your code', how could I get it to detect what button is being hovered over? since I only want the button that has is being hovered over to have the image set.

Comment: Thank you. Ill give this a try now.

Comment: @ConnorNee, see the edit in answer .. hope that helps